# Angular JS Expression is not working when I use a controller and module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just started learning Angular JS but soon I got a problem which I don't know how to resolve.

This code prints:

```
<h1>{{author[0].name}}</h1>
<p>{{author[0].title+ ', '+author[0].company}}
```

instead of:

```
<h1>MKJ</h1>
<p>Web Developer, Student Organization</p>
```

The code is given here as well:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- Declaring the ng-app -->
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Parking</title>
    <!-- Importing the angular.js script -->
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        myApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope){
            $scope.author = {
                'author': 'MKJ',
                'title': 'Web Developer',
                'company': 'Student Organization',
            };
        }
    </script>
</head>
<!-- Attaching the view to the MyController -->
<body ng-controller="MyController">
<h1>{{author[0].name}}</h1>
<p>{{author[0].title+ ', '+author[0].company}}
```

See this snippet or correct the code on [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkhuramj/xL1sn5e5/1/)?

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope){
        $scope.author = {
            'author': 'Ravy VIllalbobs',
            'title': 'Staff Author',
            'company': 'Lynda.com',
        };
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{author.title+ ', '+author.company}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.author` is an Object so you don't need to specify index in brackets here

```
<h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
<p>{{author.title+ ', '+author.company}}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xL1sn5e5/6/)

Comment: not working when I removed the square brackets as you told. Can you plz fix it on fiddlejs?

Comment: @M.KhuramJaved your fiddle has a few syntax issues and also you forgot to include angular lib, here is updated one: https://jsfiddle.net/xL1sn5e5/6/

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot Artem Petrosian! It's working now on my pc as well as fiddle!

Comment: you can also remove string concatenation in second block, because it's not necessary `{{author.title}}, {{author.company}}`